# Creating autogenerated integers not working

Tags: c#, autofixture

According to the [autofixture cheatsheet](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#autogenerated-number), I should be able to autogenerate numbers in a consecutive manner (1, 2, 3, etc.).

I am using the latest version (3.34.0) and using the exact same code as the cheat sheet shows and am continually getting random numbers, not 1, 2, 3, and so on.  Am I missing something?  Is the cheat sheet out of date?

My code:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
int i = fixture.Create<int>();
```

---

**Edit:**

Thanks Thomas - I've added an issue on github:

https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/440

Comment: Either it's a bug, or the cheat sheet is out of date... in both case, you should report it on Github

Comment: FWIW, the behavior change is [described here](http://megakemp.com/2011/09/06/behavior-changes-in-autofixture-2-2-anonymous-numbers/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In AutoFixture 3, [numbers are created using a random algorithm](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Version-History#numbers-are-random). However, the 2.x behavior can be re-applied by customizing the `Fixture` instance with a `NumericSequenceCustomization`:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize(
    new NumericSequenceCustomization());

var i1 = fixture.Create<int>();
var i2 = fixture.Create<int>();
var i3 = fixture.Create<int>();
// Prints -> 1
// Prints -> 2
// Prints -> 3

var l1 = fixture.Create<long>();
var l2 = fixture.Create<long>();
var l3 = fixture.Create<long>();
// Prints -> 4
// Prints -> 5
// Prints -> 6

var f1 = fixture.Create<float>();
var f2 = fixture.Create<float>();
var f3 = fixture.Create<float>();
// Prints -> 7
// Prints -> 8
// Prints -> 9
```

Where `NumericSequenceCustomization` is defined as:

```
internal class NumericSequenceCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Customizations.Add(new NumericSequenceGenerator());
    }
}
```

---

To create numbers that are unique per type, use the `NumericSequencePerTypeCustomization` instead:

```
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize(
    new NumericSequencePerTypeCustomization());

var i1 = fixture.Create<int>();
var i2 = fixture.Create<int>();
var i3 = fixture.Create<int>();
// Prints -> 1
// Prints -> 2
// Prints -> 3

var l1 = fixture.Create<long>();
var l2 = fixture.Create<long>();
var l3 = fixture.Create<long>();
// Prints -> 1
// Prints -> 2
// Prints -> 3

var f1 = fixture.Create<float>();
var f2 = fixture.Create<float>();
var f3 = fixture.Create<float>();
// Prints -> 1
// Prints -> 2
// Prints -> 3
```

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Out of curiosity, what is the advantage of making a customization class vs. just adding the NumericSequenceGenerator to the fixture's customizations collection directly?  Just in case you want to add more customizations to the NumericSequenceCustomization you only need to update one place?

Comment: The end-result would be the same. When you need to *encapsulate* multiple Customizations you do that by creating an `ICustomization`-derived type. You may read more about this [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/18/EncapsulatingAutoFixtureCustomizations/).

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis would you happen to know what the motivation for this change was? I can't find any discussion about it anywhere.

Comment: The discussion for this change took place [here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/2).